# How to execute a bash script?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

So I've written my first bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world!'
exit
```

I know it has the right location to bash and is executable:

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Now I want to run it from the command line, but I get an error:

```
$ myscript.sh
myscript.sh: command not found
```

So instead I try this and it works:

```
$ bash myscript.sh
hello world!
```

Is this how I will always need to execute it? I feel like I have executed other scripts without having to precede it with `bash`. How can I run myscript.sh without having to precede it with `bash`?

**Update:** Here is a good explanation of [why and how to execute a bash script](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/invoking.html).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to make the file executable. You can do that with

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

where  is the name of your script and then you have to prepend it with `./` to instruct the shell to run a file in the local directory, like:

```
./script.sh
```

You can only run files that are in your `PATH` or that you specify a path to them. `./`, the local directory, is not in the `PATH` by default because someone may use it for nefarious purposes. Imagine a script called `ls` dropped in a directory, you go inside that directory, run `ls` and that script does something bad.

While you are at it you may want to make it more portable by running shell instead of bash by using:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or by running bash no matter where it is installed as long as it is installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: I have already done that with chmod +x myscript.sh. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: You are probably missing ./  I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the advice by Fernández, precede it with a point, like this:

> ./myscript.sh

For security reasons the current directory is never included in the execution path.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to execute bash script. With example myscript.sh as the script you want to execute.

**Method 1**

execute the script as a sub process, which will trigger permission problems if not the write owner. You can change permissions by chmod.

> $ chmod +x myscript.sh
>
> $ ./myscript.sh

**Method 2**

run the script as a current user. if the bash script is well written, it should not have errors.

> $ bash myscript.sh

**Method 3**

similar to method 2 but a short cut. note that this is based on the assumption that you are using bash shell in the current session.

> $ . myscript.sh

hope this helps!:)